# ¿ Cómo retornar un multiselect seleccionado?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

Estoy haciendo un formulario en cual ya inserto los datos, pero ahora al querer editar los registros y necesito obtener los datos del multiselect ya seleccionado.

Realmente no lo logro de como hacerlo.
 este es mi formulario :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalproveeEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Crear Nuevo Proveedor</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="the-messageedit"></div>
        <form action="" id="form_proveedorEdit" method="POST" >
          <div class="form-group">
            <table style="border: 0;" class="table table-bordered">
              <head style="border: 0;">
                <tr style="border: 0;">
                  <th style="border: 0;" colspan="3">TIPO DE PROVEEDOR</th>
                </tr>
              </head>
              <tbody style="border: 0;">
                <tr>
                  <td class="bienesTDE" style="border: 0;"></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="idProveedoresIDE"   name="txtidProveE" class="form-control hidden">
            <label for="">RAZON SOCIAL <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rzonProveE" name="rzonProveE" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">NOMBRE COMERCIAL <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomProveE" name="nomProveE" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">RUC <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rucProveE" name="rucProveE" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">DIRECCION <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direProveE" name="direProveE"  >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">TELF FIJO <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telfProveE" name="telfProveE"  >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">CONTACTO <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contProveE" name="contProveE"  >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">CEL CONTACTO <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="celProveE" name="celProveE" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">E-MAIL CONTACTO <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control"  id="emailProveE" name="emailProveE" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formaPago">FORMA DE PAGO<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <select class="form-control" name="formaPagoE" id="formaPagoE" class="form-control">
              <?php foreach ($formaPago as $pago): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $pago->idPago ?>" selected><?php echo $pago->tipoPago ?></option>
              <?php endforeach?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" id="bienesE">
            <label for="">FAMILIAS<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <select class="form-control" name="idFamiliaE[]" id="idFamiliaE" multiple="multiple" class="form-control"></select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group hidden"   id="idProveedorE">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-right " data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnEdit">Actualizar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
//Código del Model

public function edit()
    {
        $idProve = $this->input->post('idProve');
        $this->db->where('idProve', $idProve);
        $query = $this->db->query(" SELECT
                                    p.*,
                                    pg.idPago,
                                    pg.tipoPago,
                                    fp.idFamilia,
                                    f.idFamilia,
                                    f.nFamilia,
                                    sf.idsFamilia,
                                    sf.nsFamilia
                                FROM
                                    proveedor p
                                LEFT JOIN familia_prove fp ON
                                    p.idProve = fp.idProveedor
                                LEFT JOIN familia f ON
                                    fp.idFamilia = f.idFamilia
                                LEFT JOIN serviciofamilia sf ON
                                    fp.familia_ids = sf.idsFamilia
                                LEFT JOIN pago pg ON
                                    p.formaPago = pg.idPago
                                WHERE
                                    p.idProve = '$idProve'"
        );
        return $query->row();
    }


    // Código de Controller

   public function edit()
   {
      $result = $this->Proveedor_model->edit();
      echo json_encode($result);
   }
```

//Codigo Ajax

```js
function edit_person(idProve) {
  var base_url = $("#base_url").val();
  $('#form_proveedorEdit')[0].reset();
  getLastId();
  getClase1();
  $('.text-danger').html(" ");
  $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
  $('.form-group').removeClass('has-success'); // clear error class
  $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string
  $('#idProveedorE').empty(); // clear error string

  $('#modalproveeEdit').modal('show');
  $('#modalproveeEdit').find('.modal-title').text('EDITAR PROVEEDOR');
  $('#form_proveedorEdit').attr('action', base_url + 'mantenimiento/logistica/proveedor/update');
  var URL = base_url + 'mantenimiento/logistica/proveedor/edit';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'ajax',
    method: 'post',
    url: URL,
    data: {
      idProve: idProve
    },
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $("select[name=idFamiliaE]").val(data.idFamilia);
      $("select[name=idFamiliaSEE]").val(data.idsFamilia);
      $("input[name=rzonProveE]").val(data.rzonProve);
      $("input[name=nomProveE]").val(data.nomProve);
      $("input[name=rucProveE]").val(data.rucProve);
      $("input[name=direProveE]").val(data.direProve);
      $("input[name=telfProveE]").val(data.telfProve);
      $("input[name=contProveE]").val(data.contProve);
      $("input[name=celProveE]").val(data.celProve);
      $("input[name=emailProveE]").val(data.emailProve);
      $("input[name=txtidProveE]").val(data.idProve);
      $("select[name=formaPagoE]").val(data.idPago);

      zona = data.tipoProvee;
      $("input:radio[name=radio]").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === zona) {
          $(this).attr('checked', true);
        }
      });
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('Could not Edit Data');
    }

  });
};

 //Condición de si es de tipo bienes o de servicios
if (zona === '1') {
  var base_url = $("#base_url").val();
  // aqui hago la consulta de todas las familias en general para que retornen 
  var URLS = base_url + 'mantenimiento/logistica/proveedor/getFamilia';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'ajax',
    method: 'post',
    url: URLS,
    async: false,
    data: {
      idClase: zona
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var html = '';
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        html += '<option  value="' + data[i].idFamilia + '">' + data[i].nFamilia + '</option>';
      }
      alert(html + " familia");
      $('#idFamiliaE').html(html);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("don't find data");
    }
  });
  // aqui hago la consulta de las familias que pertencen al proveedor que anteniromente ya habian sido registrados
  var URLSPROVE = base_url + 'mantenimiento/logistica/proveedor/getProductByProvee';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'ajax',
    method: 'post',
    url: URLSPROVE,
    async: false,
    data: {
      idProveedor: idProveedor
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var html = '';
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        datasFinal = data[i].idFamilia;
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("don't find data");
    }
  });
  $.each(datasFinal, function(i, e) {
    $("#idFamiliaE option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que ya tienes los valores que necesitas en `data.idsFamilia`, tendrias que iterar sobre ellos y seleccionarlos individualmente asi:

```js
var values=["familia1" , "familia3"];
$.each(values, function(i,e){   
    $("#IdFamiliaE option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="IdFamiliaE" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="familia1">Familia 1</option>
  <option value="familia2">Familia 2</option>
  <option value="familia3">Familia 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hola Alanfcm, tengo problemas **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 21** eso me indica, ya que primero tengo un for el cual retorna todos los datos de las familias que aun no estan registrados en la base de datos **Familia_proveedor**, luego realizo el each dentro del for con todos los datos que ya existen en familia_proveedor, osea aquellas familias que ya han sido registrados o que pertenezcan al proveedor

Comment: Ese codigo no lo pusiste, tendria que ver la linea 21 que es donde esta el error.

Comment: el 21 es el id la familia que ya pertenece al proveedor. agregue el código de ajax juntamente con el código que me proporcionaste.. puede verlo por favor

Comment: Intenta poner el `$.each` dentro de la funcion `success` de Ajax.

Comment: tambien los hice de esa manera pero me retorno el mismo error

Comment: El error dice: `No puedes usar el operador 'in' para buscar por 'lenght' en la linea 21`  Ese error no tiene nada que ver con el codigo que pusiste.  Tendria que ver el codigo para poder ayudarte.

Comment: el error era por lo que estaba usando un each dentro del for cuando lo elimine alli me funciono...